# How do you check if the last line character appears inside the string

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium

I have a String that checks last character of a string. How do you check if & appears in last line not as a last character.

```
MobileElement checkCharacter (id = "com.samsung.text")    
String check = checkCharacter.get(2).getText().trim(); 


check.charAt(check.length() - 1) == '&'
```

I tried by checking index of a string. 
Checks character in last line:

```
check.indexOf('&') >= 0
```

By Checking indexOf is this the correct way to reformat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that mean it's an error if "&" is the last character of your line?
Anyway, easiest way would be you can check first if the line contains "&":

```
if (check.contains("&"))
  <process>
```

But, if position is important, you can use your code:

```
int ampIndex = check.indexOf('&'); // returns -1 if not found
if (ampIndex >= 0 && ampIndex < check.length - 1)
  <process>
```

Comment: No it's not an error, I just need to find a character in last line. I was thinking if check.indexOf('&') >= 0 best way to do it.